# How to create a custom ColorProvider for a Visual Studio Code Extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a visual studio code simple extension in which I want to change sass file color provider to be same as the one of a css file
I have done

```
vscode.languages.registerColorProvider(DocumentSelector, DocumentColorProvider);
```

but I am not familiar with the DocumentColorProvider api and
I have declare my DocumentSelector like this:

```
let sel: vscode.DocumentSelector = { scheme: 'file', language: 'sass' };
```

in which I am trying to give a color provider to a sass file

but I haven't been able to declare the DocumentColorProvider I am not sure how to deal with it , is it a class? an interface? a hash?, 
I have read the [Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentColorProvider) and the [API Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerDocumentColorProvider) but still no clue how to do it

How Do I declare a DocumentColorProvider and the provideDocumentColors and provideColorPresentations inside the DocumentColorProvider?

also I have done this based in the typescript example of the [Hello World Extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/helloworld-sample)

Answer (score 0):

The DocumentColorProvider creates a color palette in the editor for you to select a specific color. similar to what happens in the CSS file when typing "background-color: red"[X] -> Opens a color picker!

Below is an example of how to use DocumentColorProvider:

```js
vscode.languages.registerColorProvider({language: 'html', scheme: 'file', pattern: '**/*.scss'}, {
        
        provideColorPresentations(color, context, token) {                      
            let newColor = [new vscode.ColorPresentation('My Color Pallet')];
            
            return newColor;
        },
        provideDocumentColors(document, token){         
            const positionStart = new vscode.Position(0, 5);
            const positionEnd = new vscode.Position(8, 5);
            
            const range = new vscode.Range(positionStart, positionEnd);
            const color = new vscode.Color(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
            return [new vscode.ColorInformation(range, color)];
        }
    });
```

[in vscode editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLBzu.png)